# Rails config.static_cache_control how to exclude files from cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, asset-pipeline

I'm setting long term expires headers on all of my assets. However, there are some static HTML files (for a Jekyll blog) in my public directory, that are getting cached and there is no cache busting in place for them when updated. It actually just seems to be my main `index.html` file, located in `app/public/blog`, that keeps getting caught in the cache.

Is it as simple as changing the "public" in the config?

`config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=604800"`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I keep finding it, when I look this up (I keep looking this up), so here's the answer:

No, the public in `config.static_cache_control` does NOT refer to the rails public/ directory.

In fact this whole string is a literal used as the `Cache-Control` header when serving static assets (including both public/ and sprockets-compiled assets in assets/).

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#cdns-and-the-cache-control-header for the details on how config.static_cache_control is used in rails and http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9 for the w3c docs on the meaning of the Cache-Control header.